# SQL Wildcard in Access: "%" and "_" don't works

Tags: sql, ms-access, wildcard, where-clause

I tryed some wildcards in Access in Where statement, but they don't works. For example:
This query `SELECT staff.* FROM staff;`returns:

[image]

I tryed to do a query with wildcard `SELECT staff.* FROM staff WHERE (staff.s_name LIKE "A%");`
but it returns an empty table:

[image]

What is the reason? My wildcard doesn't work

(s_name is the second column)

[image]

(look that "firstname" is the tag of "s_name" only for the view)

Comment: I can not see any column with Name `staff.s_name`. I only see `firstname` and `surname`

Comment: sorry, s_name is firstname, I changed only the tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wildcard character in Access is `*`, not `%` unlike in SQL Server.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208897(v=office.12).aspx) for details.

Comment: Unless you use ALIKE or you have chosen SQL 92, which is probably not a good idea.

Comment: It is pretty much the same as LIKE, except you can use % as a wildcard.

Answer (score -1):

No, no, no, use '*', not '%'.  Or, use 'Like'.

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/10-tips-for-using-wildcard-characters-in-microsoft-access-criteria-expressions/

https://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/like.php

https://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/like2007.php

For instance:

Like 'm*'
Result: all values that start with m

Like '*m*'
Result: all values that contain m

Like '*m'
Result: all values that end with m

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Like 'm' Result: all values that contain m" No it doesn't.