# Escape special character "[" in UPDATE SQL statement for Microsoft Access database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to run an SQL statement towards an Microsoft access database without success. The script does not fail when run, but does not update the values.

The elements that I wish to replace have following format `S7:[S7_example_234]123_ALARM`

I only wish to replace this part of the string `S7:[S7_example_234]` with `S7_example_234.`

Provided example above, running sql statement below should result in following conversion
`S7:[S7_example_234]123_ALARM` becomes `S7_example_234.123_ALARM`

Given table "myTable" and column "myColumn", I am trying to run the following

```
UPDATE myTable
SET myColumn = REPLACE(myColumn, 'S7:[[]S7_example_234[]]', 'S7_example_234')
WHERE myColumn LIKE '%S7:[[]S7_example_234[]]%'
```

As you can see, I tried escaping bracket with escape characters [] but that did not work for me.

I have also tried using * to escape brackets, without result.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/error-using-special-characters

Comment: Did you try `UPDATE myTable 
SET myColumn = REPLACE(myColumn, 'S7:[[S7_example_234]]', 'S7_example_234') 
WHERE myColumn LIKE '%S7:[[S7_example_234]]%';` this too ?

Comment: a good answer, but unfortunately no - did not work ether. Do please keep the comment as it is a plausable alternative for maybe future use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Wildcard in Access: "%" and "\_" don't works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42697537/sql-wildcard-in-access-and-dont-works)

Comment: `*` is the wildcard, not for escaping. Did you test my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape the closing `]` character, as it only has a meaning if the opening of `[` is not escaped. So you might want to try running

```
UPDATE myTable
SET myColumn = REPLACE(myColumn, 'S7:[[]S7_example_234]', 'S7_example_234')
WHERE myColumn LIKE '%S7:[[]S7_example_234]%'
```

I don't have the means to test the code above, so let me know if it does not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

As Lajos wrote, you don't need to escape the closing brackets. See [docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-wildcards-in-queries-and-parameters-in-access-ec057a45-78b1-4d16-8c20-242cde582e0b):

```
Syntax to retrieve wildcard characters from your data  
Opening bracket [   [[]  
Closing bracket ]   No special treatment needed
```

This applies to the WHERE clause.

In the `Replace()` function, you mustn't escape anything, since it doesn't use wildcards.
(The only thing to escape would be the string delimiter `' -> ''`)

The "any text" wildcard in Access is `*`, not `%`.
(But see "Understanding which set of wildcards to use" on the same page, if you don't use a normal Access query.)

So all things together, this works in an Access query:

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET myColumn = REPLACE(myColumn,'S7:[S7_example_234]', 'S7_example_234')
WHERE myColumn LIKE '*S7:[[]S7_example_234]*'
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it doesn't like using Replace to replace the string in one fell swoop.  I'd suggest trying to use Replace to replace 'S7:[' and '}' separately.  Like this:

```
    Update myTable
    set myColumn = REPLACE(REPLACE(myColumn,'S7:[',''), ']','.')
    where myColumn like '%S7:[S7_example_234]%'
```

It's a little ugly with the nested statement but I think first replacing 'S7:' with an empty string and then replacing '}' with '.' will effectively convert the string to 'S7_example_234.123_ALARM